# What format should NSUserDefaults object be for Array index

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have a func to replace an item at a specific index number.

```
let editNumber = userDefault.objectForKey("editnumber") as! String
Globals.datesArray[editNumber] = dateString
```

However, I get an error

> 'Cannot subscript a value of type '[String]' with an index of type 'String'

What format should the object from user defaults be in this scenario?

Comment: You need to pass an Int

Comment: You are loading/saving editNumber as a String and you shoulbe be saving it as an Int

Comment: I've tried passing it as Int, I still get error

Comment: Just use Int(editNumber)

Comment: The correct would be using setInteger(forkey) when saving it and integerForKey() when loading it

Comment: @LeoDabus, additionally in Swift 3 you can just use `set`

Comment: @Khoury, if you get an error passing as an int, want to tell us what it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change:

```
let editNumber = userDefault.objectForKey("editnumber") as! String
Globals.datesArray[editNumber] = dateString
```

to

```
let editNumber = userDefault.objectForKey("editnumber") as! Int
Globals.datesArray[editNumber] = dateString //this is subscripting
```

You have to subscript an array with an Int.